# PGF of independent random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_n$ be the number of successes in $n$ independent trials each with probability $\frac {\lambda}{n}$ that is,

$X_n:= \sum^n_{i=1}X_i^{(n)} $ where $P(X_i^{(n)}=1)=\frac {\lambda}{n},P(X_i^{(n)}=0)=1-\frac {\lambda}{n}$

and $ (X_i^{(n)})_{i,n∈N}$ are independent random variables.

I am trying to calculate the PGF of $X_i^{(n)}$ and hence the PGF of $X_n$

Using the definition of the PGF of a RV being the function $g_X:[0,1) → [0,1]$ given by $ g_X(\theta):=E(\theta^X)$

I have calculated that:

$g_{X_i^{(n)}}(\theta) = \frac {\lambda}{n}\theta  +(1-\frac {\lambda}{n})
 $
and $g_{X_{(n)}}(\theta) = (1+\theta(\frac{\lambda}{n}-1))^n     $

Just looking to see other peoples thoughts on these calculations

Moreover: I am also trying to deduce that, for each $k≥0,P(X_n=k)→\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$ as $ n→∞ $
but this I am struggling with however I think it may be useful to use the fact that $(1+\frac xn)^n → e^x$ as $ n→∞ $

any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: You have an algebra mistake in your last displayed equation

Comment: @MANMAID now corrected on my question, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have calculation errors:

$$E(\theta^{X_n})=E(\theta^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^{(n)}})=\Big( E(\theta^{X^{(n)}_1}) \Big)^n$$

$E(\theta^{X^{(n)}_1})=\theta\cdot\dfrac{\lambda}{n}+(1-\dfrac{\lambda}{n})=1-\color{red}{(1-\theta)}\dfrac{\lambda}{n}$

Then $$E(\theta^{X_n})=\Big(1-(1-\theta)\dfrac{\lambda}{n}\Big)^n\rightarrow e^{-(1-\theta)\lambda}\space\text{as $n\to\infty$}$$

$e^{-(1-\theta)\lambda}=e^{-\lambda}\cdot e^{\theta\lambda}=e^{-\lambda}\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\theta^k\lambda^k}{k!}\Big)$

Hence $k≥0,P(X_n=k)→\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$, as $n\to\infty$

You can do the same thing using MGF, calculation will be almost same.